# Subdomain routing in ASP.Net Core 5.0

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, routes, asp.net-core-routing

I have an application developed in dot net core 5.0 with the domain india.com
Now I have to bind dynamic subdomain to domain india.com.
Example: `br.india.com, sa.india.com, rs.india.com, ax.india.com, ....` and so on.

Challenging work is that I want all subdomain binding dynamic it won't be static. that will be handled from the database.

Anyone could please help me.
Thank you in advance.

Comment: Please provide enough code so others can better understand or reproduce the problem.

Answer (score 0):

Base of your Webserver (IIS, Nginx,...) is difference:

IIS:
web.config need add rewrite role :

Redirecting a domain to a subdirectory

```
<rule name="CustomRule" enabled="true" patternSyntax="Wildcard" stopProcessing="true">  
 <match url="*.mydomain.com" />  
 <action type="Rewrite" url="http://example.com/{R:0}" /> 
</rule>
```

Nginx:

```
server {
    listen      80;
    server_name *.example.com; 
    return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
}
```